# タブレット表示用HTMLでの長押しコピー・文字選択の無効化の方法

Tags: html, pepper

Pepperロボアプリの開発にあたり、タブレットで画面を表示させる際に長押しによるコピー・文字選択を無効化したいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

同じ画面内に文字入力部分やボタンも配置するので、タッチの無効化はしたくありません。
タッチは有効にしたまま、長押しだけを無効化したいです。
方法をご教示ください。

Answer (score 2):

以下のCSSを記入すると、ボタンのタッチは有効にしたまま、長押しによる文字選択を無効化できました。

```
body{
    -webkit-user-select:none;
}
```